# Sorting a file with integer in parentheses with no space

Tags: files, sort

I am trying to sort a file like this (which is a list of subroutine names)

```
cfn=(1370) __lib_file_MOD_file_open
fn=(1368) __universe_MOD_general_boot
fn=(916) __universe_MOD_general_main
fn=(6142) __grid_var_MOD_get_overlap
...
```

according to the integer inside parentheses. I first tried the sort command as

```
sort -t '=' -k 2 routine_list.txt
```

but then fn=(916) comes at the end of the ouput.

```
fn=(1368) __universe_MOD_general_boot
cfn=(1370) __lib_file_MOD_file_open
fn=(6142) __grid_var_MOD_get_overlap
...
fn=(916) __universe_MOD_general_main
```

but I would like the numbers to be sorted in the increasing order (916 -> 1368 -> 1370 -> ...) Is it possible to do this relatively simply by using several commands or options?

Comment: ...any [relation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gf33ueRXMzQ)?

Comment: @mikeserv my favorite char -> [singing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=arcXPaHGqR4) [sunflower](http://www.engadget.com/2010/11/10/15-minutes-of-fame-laura-shigihara-voice-of-wows-singing-sunf/) -> sun -> spectrum :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about:

```
sort -nt'(' -k2 file.txt
```

**Test :**

```
$ sort -nt'(' -k2 file.txt 
fn=(916) __universe_MOD_general_main
fn=(1368) __universe_MOD_general_boot
cfn=(1370) __lib_file_MOD_file_open
fn=(6142) __grid_var_MOD_get_overlap
```

- `-n` indicates we are sorting numerically
- `t'('` sets the delimiter as `(`
- `-k2` sets the key to `sort` as the second field i.e. starting from the digits to the end of the line.

Comment: oooooh attaching -n works... I read the man page and tried -n before, but it didn't work at that time... but now the above combination works perfectly. Thanks very much :)

Comment: @roygvib i would suggest you to use `(` as the delimiter instead of `=` as if you use `(` then sorting can start numerically from the very starting point of the second field..

Comment: Yes, it should be better to use '(' than '='. I remember I tried using both '(' and ')' as delimiters simultaneously but no success and gave up using parentheses at that time...

Answer (score 6):

Try this.  Sets the delimiter to =, and then uses field 2 from character 2 onwards (ignoring the "(").

```
sort -t= -k 2.2n file.txt
fn=(916) __universe_MOD_general_main
fn=(1368) __universe_MOD_general_boot
cfn=(1370) __lib_file_MOD_file_open
fn=(6142) __grid_var_MOD_get_overlap
```

Or even

```
sort -t\( -k 2n <foo
fn=(916) __universe_MOD_general_main
fn=(1368) __universe_MOD_general_boot
cfn=(1370) __lib_file_MOD_file_open
fn=(6142) __grid_var_MOD_get_overlap
```

Comment: hmm.. this also works as expected. It is nice to know that some characters can be skipped. Thanks very much :)