# How can I list files in sorted order into grouped sets?

Tags: sort

I already found this answer [Sorting a file with integer in parentheses with no space](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215327/sorting-a-file-with-integer-in-parentheses-with-no-space) but it doesn't cover my specifics.

I thought `ls | sort -k 7,8.2g` should work, but I get this instead:

```
A B C D E F 27 (10)
A B C D E F 27 (11)
A B C D E F 27 (12)
A B C D E F 27 (13)
A B C D E F 27 (14)
A B C D E F 27 (15)
A B C D E F 27 (16)
A B C D E F 27 (17)
A B C D E F 27 (18)
A B C D E F 27 (19)
A B C D E F 27 (1)
A B C D E F 27 (20)
A B C D E F 27 (21)
...
A B C D E F 28 (10)
A B C D E F 28 (11)
...
```

Strangely, `sort -k 8.3g` does group the (1) and then (2)... (9), (10)... but `sort -k 7,8.3g` does not sort by field 7 and then by field 8.

I want:

```
A B C D E F 27 (1)
A B C D E F 27 (2)
A B C D E F 27 (3)
...
A B C D E F 27 (9)
A B C D E F 27 (10)
A B C D E F 27 (11)
...
A B C D E F 27 (19)
A B C D E F 27 (20)
A B C D E F 27 (21)
...
A B C D E F 28 (1)
A B C D E F 28 (2)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

UGH... after clicking the sort tag and reading a few questions, I stumbled up on the "weird sort behavior" questions.

[Unexpected sort order in en_US.UTF-8 locale](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252419/unexpected-sort-order-in-en-us-utf-8-locale)

It sorts exactly how I want if I use `LC_ALL=C`